# Quarter Elapsed Calculation in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am new to Power BI and Dax so this might be obvious. DAX supports `YEAR` and `MONTH` and `TODAY` but not `QUARTER`?

I have this for Year elapsed :

```
Year Elapsed = YEARFRAC(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),1,1)-1,TODAY())
```

But I cannot make anything similar with quarter.

Comment: Take a look at TOTALQTD and TOTALYTD functions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/totalqtd-function-dax

Comment: Check out `STARTOFQUARTER` and other [Time Intelligence Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/time-intelligence-functions-dax).